# Java TextComponent Document real time updating

Tags: java, debugging, document, jtextcomponent

I am writing a simple UI debug console to be used for my software, games, etc. Currently it prints out the lines in bulk. By which I mean if I were to make a for loop counting to 5000 and print a line each time, it would count to some number, say 500, then pause, jump to 1500, pause, jump to 3000, etc. I'd like to make it act more like consoles in IDEs do, printing out the lines in real time. How can I achieve this?

```
    public void print(String line) {
    try {
        int offset = document.getLength();
        document.insertString(offset, line + "\n", attributes);
        textComponent.setCaretPosition(offset);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`document` ends up set as `textComponent.getDocument()` I am using a document because I have normal output and error output being shown as different colors.

Comment: Are you updating the `Document` from within the EDT or not?

Comment: @MadProgrammer From what I understand, the EDT is called automatically by the JVM. I call that print method from places such as the main method itself. Whether that is "within the EDT" I am not certain.

Comment: The JVM creates the EDT, but it’s up to you to make you’re updating the ui from within in

Comment: @MadProgrammer I assume by the way you're taking this, I should be updating the `Document` in the EDT? If so, how can I do this where I can still print debug lines even outside the EDT when needed?

Comment: `SwingWorker` comes to mind